# Lazy way to make variations on complex sculpt?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

this might be a stupid question but since I have only a few months of experience in 3d art I'd thought it's better to ask.

I'm making a complex sculpt of an african elephant, it's got a lot of detail and came out pretty awesome for a complete noobie. I went back to a previous save of the basic shape and thought I would revise the sculpt since I have a bit experience now and the result will be better.

I am however making this for a video game I'd like to create and I was wondering if there's a lazy or fast way of making variations without all the time consuming work of sculpting.

I'm taking about things like different shape of the eyelids, different ear shapes with different cuts, maybe some anatomical "anomalies" like a slightly misshapen skull for example, and things of that nature.

For simpler things like tusks size and shape, that's easy to do in a short time, but do any of you have a lazy guide or advice for the more subtle and detailed variations?

Thanks so much for reading through this, hit me up with any questions you might have if what I'm asking isn't clear enough!

Comment: Take a look into how to make and use shape keys.

Comment: Thanks!! from a quick look it seems to be what I'm looking for, I'll definitely look more into it and try to apply it!